# In Feedly, how do I set the feed filters to have 'Unread Only' unchecked by default?

Tags: rss-reader, feedly

When I view a feed in Feedly, the 'Unread  Only' filter is checked by default for all feeds. I have to manually go to the gear icon (Change Layout and Filtering) and uncheck 'Unread Only' for each feed that I view.

[image: 'Unread Only' filter]

Feedly remembers the setting for each individual feed, but I would like to set 'Unread Only' as unchecked by default, for all feeds.

I would like to set Feedly to be the same as Google Reader where viewing a feed will also show already read feeds, by default, for all feeds that I view. This is so I wouldn't have to manually set each feed's filters to 'Unread Only'.

Comment: You should only have to do it once for each feed, then it remembers the setting

Comment: @parkydyr It remembers the setting for each individual feed, but I would like to set 'Unread Only' as unchecked by default, for all feeds. This is so I wouldn't have to manually set each feed's filters to 'Unread Only'.

Comment: Yeah, it bugs me too. I'm even considering moving from Feedly because of "Unread Only" being on by default. For me it's comforting to be able to see read links too. This way I'm reasonably sure that I didn't miss anything.